# Portable Malware Scanning Software for Win2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, anti-virus, malware

Is there any malware/spyware/virus scanning software that can be run via USB or other means to scan a windows server 2008? It needs to be something that does not need to be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like ClamWin for this purpose. You can get it [here, in handy Portable Apps form](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/clamwin_portable). I have had trouble getting this version to update its definitions if I haven't kept it up-to-date regularly, and that generally requires downloading and installing the latest version from Portable Apps again to fix it. Not that big a deal, though -- it's only an 8MB download. And if you regularly use it/regularly keep its definitions up-to-date, you shouldn't run into this at all.

Answer (score 1):

If the server can be rebooted (or you can get to it off-hours), Combofix might do the trick for you.  HiJack this is another option, but it doesn't help you very much if you don't know what to look for and/or what might look suspicious but is actually legitimate.

There are also some scanners that you can run from the Web... or there were, it's been a while.  Does Panda still have a free web-based scan?

Also, I'd like to second Kromey's Clamwin recommendation.

If you do go ahead and decide that it's OK to use something that must be installed, beware that not all anti-malware apps will install on a machine that is running a Server OS.  Clamwin is the only free installable that I've found that will run on Server.

Comment: Combofix is **not** intended as a general purpose scanner/cleaner. It can brick your OS, and will forcibly reboot the machine if any infections are found. HiJackThis is no longer recommended since it can do nothing for the more advanced and complex malware out there today. A better tool for non-destructive analysis is [DDS](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/anti-virus/dds) which is made by the same guy who makes ComboFix. There's also [GMER](http://www.gmer.net/gmer.zip) which can uncover rootkits. There are a lot of sites out there that will analyze your logs for you for free.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SUPERAntiSpyware Portable Scanner](http://www.superantispyware.com/portablescanner.html) for this purpose. Just download it whenever you need the latest definitions and off you go. Updates tend to occur every very frequently so using a USB stick to hold it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Malwarebytes AntiMalware Portable](http://portableapps.com/node/21341).